# onclick expand div in jquery and hide another div

Tags: jquery

What should i do to when onclick expand and when click on another close the other or will be a very long page

```
<script language="javascript">
var ie4 = false;
if(document.all) { ie4 = true; }

function getObject(id) { if (ie4) { return document.all[id]; } else { return document.getElementById(id); } }
function toggle(link, divId) {
    var d = getObject(divId);
    if (d.style.display == \'\') { d.style.display = \'none\'; }
    else { d.style.display = \'\'; }
}
```

Comment: google translator doesn't work well with technical stuff. I don't understand what you mean

Comment: basic i have this on my site and this is a section for FAQ's and when people click on it they open but i like to know how can i change it so when people click on one and them click on other the 1st one will close. hope this make sense

Comment: it's impossible to give you an answer not seeing the html makrup, but from what I understand here you have to first HIDE everything and than  show the element you clicked on.

Comment: IE4 as in Internet explorer 4?

Comment: @RPM LOL i just saw that right now

Comment: You tagged your question with `jquery` although your code doesn't contain any jQuery code (the answers do). Your's is kind of the old school way to do things. You can also safely skip the IE4 check nowadays. `language="javascript"` is not needed either, `<script>` alone will work while you could do `<script type="text/javascript">`.

Comment: this is waht i mean http://www.phpprobid.com/auction-software-demo/help,page,content_pages#

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I just read your comment, and I think I understand your question better now. I think this is what you are looking for:

**Sample DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mp2xn/1/

```
<ul>
    <li class="q">Question One</li>
    <li>first answer to question one</li>
    <li>second answer to question one</li>
    <li class="q">Question two</li>
    <li>first answer to question two</li>
    <li>second answer to question two</li>
    <li class="q">Question three</li>
    <li>first answer to question three</li>
    <li>second answer to question three</li>
</ul>
```

and Jquery Code:

```
$('li:not(".q")').hide();

$('li.q').click(
    function(){
        $('li:not(".q")').slideUp();
        $(this).nextUntil('.q').slideDown();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i did not completely understand what you want to do but maybe the [toggle() function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) can help you. because one of its uses is to open a closed object (display: none --> display: block) and to hide an open object (display: block --> display: none)

the object can be for example a (div)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an HTML structure like the following:

```
<ul id="faqs">
    <li>
        <p class="heading">First FAQ question</p>
        <p>First FAQ answer</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="heading">Second FAQ question</p>
        <p>Second FAQ answer</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="heading">Third FAQ question</p>
        <p>Third FAQ answer</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would use something like this (since you put this question in the jQuery category):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#faqs > li > p:last-child').hide();
    $('#faqs > li:first-child > p:last-child').show();
    $('#faqs > li').on('click', function() {
        $('#faqs > li > p:last-child').hide();
        $(this).children('p:last-child').show();
    });
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/TPPxP/12

Comment: this is the the same one i have http://www.phpprobid.com/auction-software-demo/help,page,content_pages#